# Wifi issues on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: wireless

I have an HP Laptop (`P6L84PA#ACJ`) and have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed in it.

I cannot connect to my wifi network, it's always shown to be out of range, though my router is placed quite close. Even if it connects at times, it loses connection in a few minutes. Whereas there is no issue with my friend who uses Windows.

Is there a solution to this?

[image: Following shows the details of my driver]

Answer (score 0):

I am no  expert but I had a similar problem on my old laptop (Toshiba satellite). I found that I could connect to some net works but not others. All I did was reinstall, that seemed to work.

I have no idea if that will work but I recon it is worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and used the following:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

and the signal improved.

Finally once the signal is strong

```
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

...you add this in the file and save it... and ready. Every time you reboot that configuration is applied.

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```